# Can I add columns in MS Project Pro to display time-phased costs?

Tags: ms-project, cost-management

Can I add columns in MS Project Pro to display time-phased costs? I would like to see a cost column for each year of the project. The year-column would only include costs for that year. I can almost do it by using formulas in custom-cost columns, but the tasks split between years are missed.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about a particular tool? Or an approach?

Comment: In a tool, I would like to see the columns in MS Project Pro project schedule

Comment: It is worth mentioning MS Project in your post and including it as a tag as you will get more responses. I'm going to edit your post and add the MS Project tag now.

Answer (score 1):

Cost is timephased in either the Task Usage or Resource usage view (right hand side).  Add Cost (right click in the background of the right hand side and choose Cost from the shortcut menu).  Zoom out as needed.